# androidx widget AppCompatImageView with png source wont inflate in Lollipop device?

Tags: android, imageview, androidx

I converted my project to use androidx components.

> I have an image view that works on android q emulator and Nougat but shows error on lollipop emulator.

Here's the xml files related portion:

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/scalelines" 
            />
```

The sorce image is in png format. Although it works with android q. Gives error given below:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at com.example.e.Fragments.Home.onCreateView(Home.java:93)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2595)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2076)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1821)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:230)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
    at android.view.View
```

How can I make this work with png image source without crashing in lollipop or older devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think you have placed your image inside `drawable-v24` instead of
> `drawable`. Goto Project Structure of your app to verify it or if you want just move files to drawable .

Comment: yeah this was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the attached code or exception, why this is crashing. Please attach your complete layout file, and maybe the theme you use to inflate your fragment (it could be possible that you have an error in the theme) . Furthermore, as per the documentation of the [AppCompatImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatImageView) you shouldn't be directly using the AppCompatImageView in your layout. It will be used automatically and the top level activity is provided by appcompat.

Comment: It is converted, I did not add it directly. I used normal imageview first.